# What's the quickest way to rename all property names in a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

Say, I have an object that looks like this:

```
const a = {
  prop1: "val1",
  prop2: "val2",
  prop3: "val3",
  prop4: "val4",
}
```

And I want something like this derived from `a`:

```
const b = {
   something_prop1: "val1",
   something_prop2: "val2",
   something_prop3: "val3",
   something_prop4: "val4",
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this without having to create an intervening array of keys or running a `for` or `foreach` loop?

Comment: Any reasonable implementation will necessarily require a loop somewhere, even if abstracted behind an array method. I suppose you could do it without arrays if you knew exactly which keys exist on the object (and which keys you want to replace them with) in advance, but that would be very silly and WET

Comment: without a loop, you say?

Comment: I meant without a for or foreach. I tried using map(), but the furthest I could go was retrieve all keys into an array.

Comment: You just can't do N operations by doing 1 operation. This will obviously need iteration with a loop.

Comment: @TheLearner `map` or `reduce` will perform a loop, just it isn't in your code.

Comment: I understand that. The objective is to keep the code as clutter-free as practically possible. A background loop isn't what I'm worried about, which is why I tried map().

Comment: Well if you really do not want to use any kind of loop, you can use Proxy and while accessing `proxy.something_prop1` you can strip `something_` in the getter and return `a.prop1` as the result :D

Comment: actually you need to pull the number from the key as well, or use replacing with a JSON string. but any operation requires some loops, explicit or implicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could map new objects and build a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const
    a = { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2", prop3: "val3", prop4: "val4" },
    b = Object.assign(...Object.entries(a).map(([k, v]) => ({ ['something_' + k]: v })));

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
const a = {
  prop1: "val1",
  prop2: "val2",
  prop3: "val3",
  prop4: "val4",
};
const b = {};
Object.keys(a).forEach(k => b[`something_${k}`] = a[k]);

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `reduce` if your point is not to use `for` or `forEach`.

```js
const a = {
  prop1: "val1",
  prop2: "val2",
  prop3: "val3",
  prop4: "val4",
}

const transformKeys = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => (acc[`something_${key}`] = obj[key], acc), {});

const b = transformKeys(a);

console.log(b);
```